# C# consecutive and redundant null checks

Tags: c#, null

I am working on a C# application and I want to support multiple themes, so I wrote a `ThemeManager` class that can check, load and apply a specific theme. A theme is considered valid, when all of it's member variables are set (not `null`). If a theme is invalid I want to throw an `IncompleteThemeException`. However the following code feels a bit stupid...

```
public static void Load(Theme theme)
{
    AccentBrush = theme.AccentBrush ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    AccentBrushLight = theme.AccentBrushLight ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    WarningBrush = theme.WarningBrush ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    WarningBrushLight = theme.WarningBrushLight ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    ErrorBrush = theme.ErrorBrush ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    ErrorBrushLight = theme.ErrorBrushLight ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    MainBackgroundBrush = theme.MainBackgroundBrush ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    InactiveDecoratorBrush = theme.InactiveDecoratorBrush ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    SecondaryBackgroundBrush = theme.SecondaryBackgroundBrush ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    MainTextBrush = theme.MainTextBrush ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    SecondaryTextBrush = theme.SecondaryTextBrush ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    DefaultPasswordIndicatorBrush = theme.DefaultPasswordIndicatorBrush ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();

    AccentColor = theme.AccentColor ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    MainBackgroundColor = theme.MainBackgroundColor ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
    AccentColorLight = theme.AccentColorLight ?? throw new IncompleteThemeException();
}
```

I thought about maybe using reflection to somehow iterate over all members of the theme instance to check if one of them is null, but I'm unsure what the best solution to this would be in terms of readability, performance and extensibility in the future.

How can this be improved?

Comment: _"I thought about maybe using reflection to somehow iterate over all members of the theme instance ..."_ Did you make a working attempt already? Usually we don't write new code for you. It seems to be a reasonable idea doing so though.

Comment: What type of project are working on ? ASP.NET ?

Comment: It's an AvaloniaUI project

Comment: @FrederikHoeft is Theme class a part of Avalonia ? or is it a user defined class ?

Comment: It is a user defined class and it's expected to grow in the future when it comes to the number of public member variables

Comment: I would advice against throwing an exception at the first missing property. Instead, compile a list of errors and serve that to the user, so they don't have to fix every item one by one until all of them are OK. I recently worked on a project where the remote endpoint threw an exception at the slightest mistake (often caused by bad documentation or a bad implementation on their side), requiring me to contact them for almost every problem. This was a pointlessly elongated process that could have gone way smoother if I'd gotten a list of all errors in one go.

Comment: The easiest (though certainly not _best_) solution here would be to not null check, catch **any** null reference exception, and then throw your `IncompleteThemeException`. There are many things you could've tried here, did you attempt any improvement over the current code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since your `Theme` class is a user defined class, you could do something like :

```
public class Theme
{   // Cache the reflection once, then reuse it
    private static readonly PropertyInfo[] _properties = typeof(Theme).GetProperties();
    
    // properties 
    
    public Theme() { }
        
    
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        foreach(var property in _properties)
        {   
            var value = property.GetValue(this, null);

            if (value == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

Or if you are into Linq (thanks Peter Csala):

```
public bool IsValid() => _properties.All(property => property.GetValue(this, null) != null);
```

Then this should go like :

```
public static void Load(Theme theme)
{
    if(!theme.IsValid()) { throw new IncompleteThemeException();    }
    
    AccentBrush = theme.AccentBrush; 
    //... etc..
}
```

**UPDATE :**
@Blindy suggested to use `static` reflection and reuse it instead, to avoid creating multiple reflection instances. Which I mostly agree. So, I've updated the code so it can reuse the reflection instance (this including the Linq version as well). (Thanks to Blindy)

Comment: You can also use Linq for validation: `public bool IsValid() => this.GetType().GetProperties().All(property => property.GetValue(this, null) != null)`

Comment: @PeterCsala I've included that in my answer, thank.

Comment: Please cache those reflection properties, the way you wrote it it will call very expensive virtual reflection functions over and over every time you call this function (which we don't know how often it is). Use a `static readonly PropertyInfo[] PropertiesToCheck = typeof(Theme).GetProperties();`

Comment: @Blindy thanks mate, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 16):

Two things to think about:

1. Could you code this so it's impossible to create an invalid `Theme` instance thus not having to worry about it in this method?
2. How does a consumer know what is invalid about their instance?

For 1, you could simply have a constructor that takes all of the arguments and throws if any are invalid. A pattern that can also work well is having defaults - that way, a theme can just override part of the default theme rather than having to specify everything.

For 2, add some context to your exceptions:

```
throw new IncompleteThemeException("Default Password Indicator Brush was not specified");
```

However, I would probably lean towards having a mutable builder class with defaults and have a create method there. Consuming it could look like:

```
var builder = new ThemeBuilder(Theme.Default /* or existing theme etc. */)
     .WithErrorBrush(myErrorBrush)
     .WithAccentBrush(myAccentBrush);

// Now build it.
var theme = builder.Build();
```

That seems like it would make it easier for consumers to use a `Theme` as all instances would always be valid and you get the ease of use via the builder class. A nice bonus is that you can add new properties to the theme without breaking consumers. They get a sensible default that they can choose to override if needed. You don't just start throwing `IncompleteThemeException`.

Answer (score 6):

It sure looks somehow clumsy like it is. You should place such stuff deep down the road, meaning you should have a method inside `Theme` e.g. `IsThemeValid()`  where you can place all these `null` checks.

Hence you would only have one method to maintain instead of each occurrence where you pass a `Theme`.

Comment: I would use the name `IsValid` because `theme.IsThemeValid` is needlessly wordy, and `if (theme.IsValid)` is closer to English.  I'd also make it a property since methods are thought by many to be *verbs,* and I wouldn't want to call it `GetIsValid()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your `Theme` to be unaware of what is valid or invalid which makes sense as `ThemeLoader` may be responsible for defining it, you may try writing something like ef core's fluent api.

Something like following;

```
    var validator = new ThemeValidator<Theme>();
    validator.Property(theme => theme.AccentBrush)
        .IsRequired();
    validator.Propert(theme => theme.AccentBrushLight)
        .IsRequired();
    validator.validate(theme); // raises exception
```

This may look like what you do as you have to define for each variable. But i think, this way is open for extension as different conditions other than null check become necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The code is not too far off of the of execution and I take your reflection proposal as a means to work around limitations in the language.  This is a fairly straightforward use case for code generation.

Something [like T4](https://blogs.u2u.be/peter/post/Using-T4-to-automatically-generate-your-entities) or [AOP via PostSharp](https://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_patterns_contracts_notnullattribute) or similar could easily generate the same code without the potential typos, readability, and maintenance issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
#nullable enable

namespace Examples {

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;

    public class Program {

        public static void Main( String[] args ) {
            var theme = new Theme();

            var valid = theme.IsValid( out var invalidPropertyNames );

            if ( valid ) {
                Debug.WriteLine( $"All properties on {nameof( theme )} are valid." );
            }
            else {
                foreach ( var name in invalidPropertyNames ) {
                    Debug.WriteLine( $"Found invalid property {name}." );
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class Theme {

        /// <summary>
        ///     Cache the reflection once.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly PropertyInfo[] _properties = typeof( Theme ).GetProperties( BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public );

        private Int32? Test1 { get; } = 1;
        private Int32? Test2 { get; } = null;
        private Int32? Test3 { get; } = 3;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Run a check to see if all properties are valid (not null).
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns true if all properties do not have a  null value.</returns>
        public Boolean IsValid() => this.IsValid( out _ );

        /// <summary>
        ///     Output a list of any invalid (null) properties.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="InvalidPropertyNames"></param>
        /// <returns>Returns true if all properties do not have a  null value.</returns>
        public Boolean IsValid( out IList<String> InvalidPropertyNames ) {
            InvalidPropertyNames = _properties.Where( info => info.GetValue( this, null ) == null ).Select( info => info.Name ).ToList();

            return !InvalidPropertyNames.Any();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please review the code given by the OP and describe why your code is better. This is a code review website and code only answers, might not be clear enough for the OP to understand why your code would be better